# including library and dll into c++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, dynamic-linking

I have a third party library (say, tp.lib) and the third party dll (say, tp.dll)  which I need to use in my C++ project (my project makes a dll, lets call it my.dll).

I have included the library with the #pragma comment(lib, "libraryname") in the header file
 and also included the path of the library file in the *configurationproperties->linker->additional library directories* in my C++ Visual Studio project.

The code compiles and links okay. but fails to execute. When I used depends to check if i am missing something, I observed that the tp.dll is not found. The tp.dll resides in the same library folder where the tp.lib resides.

What should I do so that tp.dll gets included to my.dll?

Comment: Do you want to statically link tp.dll into my.dll so that you can deploy only my.dll and all the code will be there? Or will you be ok with deploying both tp.dll and my.dll and the application executing without error?

Comment: i want to statically link tp.dll. so that only thing i have to do is deploy my.dll. how can i make this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search path at runtime does not include the folder where you put the lib library, so putting the DLL with the lib is not enabling the OS to find it at runtime. You can add that to the path, or move the DLL. The [list of search precedence is on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

DLLs have a different search path.  Quote below from [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> With both implicit and explicit linking, Windows first searches for "known DLLs", such as Kernel32.dll and User32.dll. Windows then searches for the DLLs in the following sequence:
>
> 1. The directory where the executable module for the current process is located.
> 2. The current directory.
> 3. The Windows system directory. The GetSystemDirectory function retrieves the path of this directory.
> 4. The Windows directory. The GetWindowsDirectory function retrieves the path of this directory.
> 5. The directories listed in the PATH environment variable.
>
> Note
> The LIBPATH environment variable is not used.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "include the dll into another dll". You need to either deploy them together, or put the dependency dll in a place where [Windows will find it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: when you say "deploy them together" what is the way to do it ?

Comment: just copy them into same folder, i.e. point 1) in provided link